# Is it possible to have google assistant launch a mail client on a phone

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

We noticed Google assistant can launch other apps like spotify
Is it possible to have google assistant launch a mail client on a phone

Similar to use mailto: on the web, and be able to pass over the subject and body

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. But you can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/google_assistant) to [send mails or automate other stuff](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7194656).

Comment: Thanks, but I want google assistant to launch the mail client when the user is on google assistant so the user can choose who to email, like when forwarding a referral code